# What is the meaning of the following statement?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Let $x_n$ be a sequence that converges to a non-zero limit. Prove that all except finitely many terms $x_n$ are non-zero.

I am trying to use contradiction to prove, but I am confused what "all except finitely many terms $x_n$ are non-zero" means. Does it mean finitely zero's or all are zero? If I don't know the meaning, I can't negate. Could someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

> Prove that all except finitely many terms $x_n$ are non-zero.

You can read this as

> Prove that all terms $x_n$ are non-zero, except finitely many [terms $x_n$ are zero].

Basically, they want you to prove that only finitely many $x_n$ can be $0$ if $\lim x_n\neq 0$. This will probably be done easiest with a contradiction: assume there are infinitely many, then for each $N$ there is an $n$ with $n>N$ and $x_n=0$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: If all are non-zero, how could there be finitely many are zero

Comment: All are non-zero, except finitely many. They are not *all* non-zero, but there are only finitely many $x_n$ equal to $0$, making the amount of $x_n$ that are non-zero, in that sense, "almost all terms"

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence has the same amount of terms than natural numbers: For every $n \in \Bbb{N}$ you have a corresponding $x_n$. All except finite means that every $x_n = 0$ except for a finite number of terms.

How does this can be negated? What is the negation of $\textit{all except finite}$?

> There are infinitely many terms $x_n = 0$

To be sure this negation if correct, try thinking what would be the negation of the negation, and verify it is exactly: All except finite $x_n$ are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the "all"  confuses you when it's modified by "except". You can replace

> all except finitely many are nonzero

by

> only finitely many are zero

without changing the meaning.

The negation of either statement is

> infinitely many are zero

Answer (score 0):

$limx_n=a\neq 0 (n\rightarrow \infty)\  iff$ for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>n_0$ then $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$

Take $\epsilon=\frac{|a|}{2}$ ($|a|$ is the distance from $a$ to 0).
We know that there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>n_0\ \ |x_n-a|<\frac{|a|}{2}$. That implies that for every $n>n_0\ \ x_n>0$ (if it's not clear why this is true, try to draw a real line and the points $a, x_n$ and $\frac{|a|}{2}$ neighborhood of the point $a$). That means that if there are some $x_n=0$, they are among $x_1,\dots,x_{n_0}$. The maximum number of zero elements is $n_0$, which is finite.